# How to stop read call to controller if e.filter is null (HTML Razor syntax)

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

While Kendo Grid development (using HTML Razor syntax , MVC, Jquery and JavaScript) if my filters are empty I don't want to call the controller or Read the data. How I can do that?
here is my code snippet
Razor Code snippet--

```html
 Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller").Data("getFilters"))
```

JSCode

```js
 getFilters= function (e) 
{
 if (e.filter  === null)
 //do nothing and stop
 else 
 return { filters }
}
```

Help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stop the request in the DataSource's `RequestStart` event:

```
function requestStart(e) {
    if (!this.filter()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

You might want to extend this snippet to inform the user that no new data were loaded due to the empty filter. Otherwise the user might be confused why the result did not change if he submits an empty filter.

Comment: Don't forget: you can accept this answer if it was the correct or useful solution. Read more about accepting answers on https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did

Added event for on filter

```html
Filter("onFiltering")
```

JS code

```js
function onFiltering()
{
     if (e.filter === null)
      {
       e.preventDefault();
       //display pop up for confirmation that no filters are applied and user still want to continue please select Yes
       //if Yes then 
       
       $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read()
       
      }
  }
```

Thanks everyone and appreciate your answers/comments.

Happy coding